# What does "liabilities" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From CNBC's article "[Will AI spark a wave of job losses in banking? This what the experts think](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/20/as-facebook-google-microsoft-invest-in-ai-this-is-the-outlook-for-banking.html)". (Emphasis mine)

> "There's a lot of **liabilities**," said panelist Matthew Blume, director for client technology in ASEAN at financial services provider Thomson Reuters. AI systems, he said, could easily be gamed.

What does "liabilities" meaning in this context?

Comment: Have you [checked a dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+liabilities)? What did you find that you did not understand?

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/liability#liability__4

Comment: I did but I still couldn't understand it.

Comment: Blume is using it as a sloppy synonym for "risk".

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was confused by the grammar mistake in that sentence: "there's": singular, but "liabilities": plural.

Comment: It's not a grammar mistake. It's common to use "there's" with a plural noun: see [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is referring to definition 2 in that dictionary link: "things that cause you problems", although that definition needs to be expanded to include **potential** problems, ie "risks" (this definition of liability is synonymous with (or very close to) the noun form of "risk").

The panelist is referring to the gaming (ie careful exploitation of the system to elicit unwanted behaviours) of AI systems as an example of one of the liabilities, ie risk factors, of using AI.

Other definitions of "liability" include this risk/potential problem aspect, eg http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/liability